# How could I set up this variable properly? - Python

Tags: python

How could I set a variable up for +, - and *?

example of what I'm trying to do for subtraction

`difficulty = '-'`

`FinalAnswer=((Answer1) (Difficulty) (Answer2))`

I'm sure this is actually super simple and I'm having a massive brain fart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cleanest approach here is to use `operator`, e.g.:

```
import operator


operators = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub}
x = operators['-'](a, b)
```

---

If you need to evaluate a string like `10 + 3`, you could use `eval()`, e.g.:

```
s = '10 + 3'
eval(s)
```

As pointed out in the comment by @Błotosmętek, you cannot use the otherwise far safer option `ast.literal_eval()` in this case.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval('10 + 3')` raises `ValueError('malformed string')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `eval`:

```
FinalAnswer= eval('Answer1' + Difficulty + 'Answer2')
```

but this is dangerous if the strings come from user input. 
Alternatively, you could do something like that:

```
FinalAnswer = { '-': Answer1 - Answer2, 
                '+': Answer1 + Answer2, 
                '*': Answer1 * Answer2 } [Difficulty]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have your program structured you should just be able to do this with a little bit of control flow.

```
if difficulty == 1:
    operation = '+'
elif difficulty == 2:
    operation = '-'
elif difficulty == 3:
    operation = '*'
elif difficulty == 4:
    operation = '/'
```